# WebView should use same cookies as fetch

Tags: react-native

I have done a sign in to my app using the native fetch API. I now need to load an image, so am loading it in a `<WebView>`, however the webview is not using the cookies from the fetch API outside of the webview. Is it possible to tell webview to use those cookies?

Comment: You do know you can load images by url without a webview, right?

Comment: Thanks @ChrisGeirman yes however I need that pinch to zoom feature which WebView was giving me. I also had a need to scale the image, but pixelated scale - which I was acheiving via css with `image-rendering: pixelated;`

Comment: Also I was mistaken, the cookies are being shared it seems, do you know if this is a true as a feature/fact @ChrisGeirman ? Or am i just getting lucky here?

Comment: Nice, pinch to zoom is a nice give me. Not sure about the cookies, sorry

Comment: I'll check out if its a feature and on verify will report back. :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can post a message containing your cookies content to your Webview using postMessage().

You need to get the ref of the Webview then post the message to your webview.

```
let webviewRef = null;

const cookiesContent = 'My cookies bla bla bla'

render() {
    return (
        <WebView
            onLoad={() => webviewRef.postMessage(cookiesContent)}
            ref={webview => { webviewRef = webview; }}
            source={{ uri: 'https://YourUrl' }}
        />
    );
}
```

Then in your Website you can create the cookies and use it

```
<script>
    document.addEventListener("message", function(data) {
        document.cookie=`cookiesName=${data.data}`;
    });
</script>
```

If you aren't the owner of the website you can still try to inject the javascript with injectedJavaScript props of Webview Component.

```
const JsCode = 'document.addEventListener("message", function(data) {
        document.cookie=`cookiesName=${data.data}`;
    });';

  <WebView
        injectedJavaScript={JsCode}
        onLoad={() => webviewRef.postMessage(cookiesContent)}
        ref={webview => { webviewRef = webview; }}
        source={{ uri: 'https://YourUrl' }}
    />
```

Comment: This is superb thank you @Gabriel - how can I get the stored cookies from the fetch API? Is making a dummy request and getting the headers the only way?

Answer (score 0):

You can use https://github.com/react-native-community/cookies to get cookies and set them back